# slash vs question mark

Tags: php, directory

I am running a website like twitter where users can view their posts by going to

```
www.mywebsite.com/post.php?pid=555
```

Where 555 is the id of the post they request, but I noticed when you view your status on twitter you go to something like for example

```
https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/484722240684965888
```

where I think 484722240684965888 is the id of the status.

so does twitter have a folder for every status on their website?

Comment: Nahhh ... these URLs are rewritten in `htaccess`

Comment: Could elaborate more please.

Comment: Naaa again .. Search for `Rewrite URLS with htaccess` on Google

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

This is likely done using a [rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) such as Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

I would recommend that you should read up on that. Depending on your server configuration you would likely do this through a `.htaccess` file